# Flutter - Detect TexField on tap

Tags: dart, flutter

I maked a flutter app in windows and all works, but when i tried to compile to iOS throw a unexpected error. In the Textfield detects that the 'onTap'  isn´t a a correct parameter. I don´t know what happens, in windows doesn´t return this error. Anyway. anybody know how fix this and what is the correct way to detect 'onTap' on texfield?

```
 new Container(
          color: Colors.blue[300],
          child: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new Card(
              child: new ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                title: new TextField(
                  onTap: () { <--- The named parameter 'onTap' isn´t defined
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this but doesn´t work

```
 title: new GestureDetector(
            child: new TextField(
          controller: searchController,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Buscar parcela', border: InputBorder.none),
        )),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new EstatesPage(
                      parcela: widget.parcela,
                      dropdownItem: dropdownSelection)));
        },
```

**UPDATE 2**: SOLUTION

I updated flutter and brew. The error disappeared.

Comment: What if you use - `CupertinoTextField` Widget ?

Comment: And how can i use this widget? I never use Cupertino elements.

Comment: Wrap your `TextField` in `GestureDetector` and handle `onTap` in it.  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: I updated question with a piece of code that i tried but doesn´t work.

Comment: Could you add your console logs for the error? It can help to identify the problem. Also your 'flutter doctor' messages if anything unusual.

Comment: @Gunhan see "Update 2" in the question. `onTap` was added recently https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/24536

Comment: @Gunhan sorry, he just added that part.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15882#issuecomment-426283823 
 in this link, you can find a way. briefly: wrap your TextField with:
```Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: IgnorePointer(
                child: TextField(
                  
                ),
              ),
            ),```

Answer (score 12):

you can wrap your textfield in `IgnorePointer` widget. It disables all the gestures on its children. This will make gesture detector work.

```
title: new GestureDetector(
            child: new IgnorePointer (
                child: new TextField(
              controller: searchController,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Buscar parcela', border: InputBorder.none),
            ))),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new EstatesPage(
                      parcela: widget.parcela,
                      dropdownItem: dropdownSelection)));
        },
```

Comment: OnTap is not working.

Comment: it will work use IgnorePointer :) @Minion

Answer (score 10):

TextField has `onTap` property like GestureDetector which makes it very easy. If you only want the `onTap` functionality set `readOnly` to `true`.

```
    TextField(
      readOnly: true,
      onTap: () {
        //Your code here
      },
      [...]
    );
```

Similarly for TextFormField:

```
    TextFormField(
      readOnly: true,
      onTap: () {
        //Your code here
      },
      [...]
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

`GestureDetector` didn't work for me. I used InkWell.

```
child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _selectDate(context);
              },
              child: const IgnorePointer(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Date',
                    hintText: 'Enter Date',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_outlined),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I use **InkWell** instead of **GestureDetector**

```
                InkWell(
                  child: IgnorePointer(
                    child: TextField(
                    )
                  ),
                 onTap: (){
                
                 }
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

**use readonly: false for on tap action in text field**

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  onTap: () {
    // open dialogue
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I either use **InkWell** with **IgnorePointer** or Gesture detector with readOnly set to true. It all depends on what is your aim here.

Inkwell creates the interaction for touch for the TextField whilst the IgnorePointer makes the TextField not tappable.

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
    debugPrint('TAP TAP TAP');
   },
  child: IgnorePointer(
   child: TextField( decoration: customDateField(),)));
```

Similarly, Gesture Detector with readOnly on the TextField set to false.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
    debugPrint('TAP TAP TAP');
      },
       child: TextField(
       readOnly: true,
       decoration: customDateField(),));
```

Also TextField onTap built-in already handles the touch. You could also do

```
TextField(
         readOnly: true,
         decoration: customDateField(),
         onTap: () {
         debugPrint('Open Calendar');
                   },
         ),
```

Essentially GestureDetector is a go-to if you don't want to add any super effects that Inkwell provides.